# Simplify Boolean Algebra Expression

Tags: boolean-algebra

The problem is to simplify:
$$ xz+\bar{x}y+zy $$
I have an answer key that says the answer is:
$$ xz + \bar{x}y $$
I have no idea how they got this expression, though. The first thing I tried was to find the dual. Setting the original expression equal to some variable c, I got
$$ \bar{c} = \bar{x}\bar{y} + \bar{z}x + \bar{z}\bar{y} $$
This, however, doesn't simplify anything. Taking the dual of this only gets me the original expression again. How do I get the $ zy $ term to drop out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the $zy$ term to drop out by conjoining it with $\,1 = x + \bar x\,$ first, and then distributing $zy=yz$ over $x + \bar x$.

Then, by "reverse" distribution (twice) you collect common factors (there will be two terms with $xz$, and two terms with $\bar xy$). Doing this makes nice things happen:

$$\begin{align} xz+\bar{x}y+zy 
& = xz+\bar xy + (1)zy \\ \\
& = xz + \bar xy + (x + \bar x)yz\\ \\ 
& = xz + \bar xy + xyz + \bar x y z\\ \\
& = xz(1 + y) + \bar xy(1 + z)\\ \\
& = xz(1) + \bar xy(1)\\ \\
& = xz + \bar xy
\end{align}$$

Comment: Interesting. This doesn't seem like an obvious thing to do. I suppose something like this would just be a consequence of pattern recognition. Does this come up often?

Comment: It comes up here and there. You're right that it isn't, initially, intuitive. In some cases, using this "trick" is a bit more intuitive, but as with most things, it becomes more intuitive with practice. Once you see it a few times, and understand why it works, plus actively look for situations to apply it, it will stick with you.

Answer (score 1):

- solution

  $xz + x'y + yz = xz(1+y) +  x'y(1+z) + zy\\
                =xz + xzy + x'y + x'yz + zy\\
                =xz + zy(x + x') + x'y + yz\\
                =xz + 2yz + x'y$

on comparing LHS and RHS , we get
$$\Rightarrow yz=0
\Rightarrow xz + x'y + yz = xz + x'y$$